# Fatal Error on Advance search

Tags: advanced-search

When running a CRM advanced search. If we try Adv Search>Display results as'Realted contacts' and choose and Rel type. The hit search we get the DB error.

CiviCRM: 5.13.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is now [fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14409) in 5.14. You can try applying patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14409.patch) or upgrade CiviCRM to 5.15.1.

Thanks

Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

The error establishing a database connection error basically means that for some reason or another the PHP code was unable to connect to your MySQL database to retrieve the information it needs to fully build that page.Here are how to solve it： https://docsbay.net/how-to-fix-error-establishing-a-database-connection-error